# Hide Negative Values in Chart Y Axis Swift

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I am using library https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts for displaying data fetched from server.

Now everything is working as expected but when there is zero values coming from server I get negative values on Y-Axis (PS image)

[image] but i could not get it done.

Can you please guide me how to remove negative values from Y-Axis.

I did try to [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019464/negative-values-not-displayed-in-line-charts-using-ios-charts-using-swift) [Link2](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/3850)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to hide negative values is to add the minimum value for Y axis.

```
chartOutlet.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
```